# Unable to pass parameter in onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

I have a rich modal panel. Inside that I have a rich:picklist. And I have a Save button in the same panel. When I click on Save button, I want to send selected ids as parameters in onclick attribute of the button. (I am using a:commandLink for button). But anyhow I am unable to send the parameter. When I check it with alert inside the javascript method, it is coming as null.

My rich:picklist code is

```
<h:panelGroup id="distTypesPanel">  
    <div class="form-row fl" style="height: 180px; width: 400px;">  
        <label for="dist_type">Distribution Type:<span  
            class="required">*</span> <h:message for="distTypesList"  
            errorClass="error" />  
        </label>  
        <rich:pickList id="distTypesList" copyAllControlLabel=" "  
            copyControlLabel=" " removeControlLabel=" "   
            removeAllControlLabel=" " value="#{asset.selectedDistTypes}"  
            converter="javax.faces.Integer">  
            <f:selectItems  
                value="#{lookupManager.setUpDMRLkpDistTypeMap()}" />  
        </rich:pickList>  
    </div>  
</h:panelGroup>
```

Save Button code is :

```
<a:commandLink  styleClass="btn green-btn save-btn fr"  onclick="updateLOB(#{asset.selectedDistTypes})" reRender="updateLOBPanel"  
    oncomplete="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('updateLOBPanel');document.getElementById('lobMasterCheckBox').checked=false;"   
    ajaxSingle="true" style="margin: 10px; align:right;" >  
<span> Save </span>   
</a:commandLink>
```

Javascript method is :

```
function updateLOB(selectedDistTypes){
    alert(selectedDistTypes);
    var idList = jQuery("#assetSearchResults").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    var idListToUpdateLOB = idList.join(",");
    if(idListToUpdateLOB.length >0){
        updateLOBOfAssets(idListToUpdateLOB);
    }
}
```

Js FUnction :

```
<a:jsFunction name="updateLOBOfAssets" oncomplete="gridReload();"
           action="#{assetManager.updateLOB()}" ajaxSingle="true">
           <a:actionparam name="param1" assignTo="#{assetManager.idList}" />
        </a:jsFunction>
```

selectedDistTypes is coming as null. Can you please help me in sending param correctly?

Answer (score 2):

When the page is being rendered all the EL expressions are resolved. That means that your commandButton is set to `onclick="updateLOB([])"` because the list was empty at the time the button was rendered.

There are several ways to do what you want to do but I don't know what you are doing with the IDs in your `updateLOBOfAssets` function. The easiest thing might be to retrieve the IDs from the bean, rather than passing them around with JavaScript.

Comment: @Makhiel.. If I get the selectedDistTypes, I have to pass that list along with idListToUpdateLOB to updateLOBOfAssets and from there I am calling bean method.

Comment: So if you are calling a bean method can't you use the bean to retrieve the necessary values?

Comment: Inside bean method, I am getting null values. I guess the picklist is not setting the values. And updateLOBOfAssets(idListToUpdateLOB) is an a:jsFunction . In that a:jsFunction , I am calling bean method. I have set paramerter for idListToUpdateLOB . I tried setting param value for selectedDistTypes but thn also getting null. Don't know what is the mistake I have done?

Comment: I have edited my question by adding a:jsFunction. Can you pls tell me what is the change I need to make in order to get id's of selectedDistTypes inside my bean method?

Comment: You should use a logger in your bean to see what's happening. It might be just that the bean is updated after the JS functions are executed (in which case you should use oncomplete) or your bean has a bad scope. There should not be anything preventing the list from being processed. Are the list and the button in the same form?

Comment: Yes. Both list and buttons are in same form. Bean is stateful and scope is @Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION). Even my lead here saw the code and no mistakes found. Don't know what is wrong. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
onclick="updateLOB('#{asset.selectedDistTypes}')"
```

Doesn't look like you quoted the value.